# Wait until MongoDB has completed its query without using callbacks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have an issue with the asynchrous programming model in Node.js.

I know this has been asked before, but so far I haven't found anything that I can use to solve my issue.

**How do I force `console.log` from running before `dbQueryName` has been invoked and `username` has gotten its value from it?**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

function dbQueryName() {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");

        dbo.collection("users").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            return result.name
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

var username = dbQueryName();

// Wait until dbQueryName() has been invoked and username has gotten its value before running this
console.log(username);
```

I have managed to get it working using a `callback` parameter in the function, but is there a way to do this with less code and indentation?

```
function dbQueryName(callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");

        dbo.collection("users").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            callback(result.name)
            db.close();
        });
    });
}


dbQuery(function(result){
    var username = result
    console.log(username);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you are not passing a callback to MongoClient.connect or collection.findOne, it returns a promise.

But you need to add another function to use async await

```
init()


async function dbQueryName() {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db("mydb");


    const user = await dbo.collection("users").findOne({})
    return user.name
}
async function init() {
    try {
        const name = await dbQueryName()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up going with the `callback` solution because I found that solution to be the most understandable at this point. The asynchrous concepts are still difficult to grasp.